# why my web application can't recognize angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I am a beginner in angular, I am trying to load and use it in my web application (VS) but each time I get problems with recognizing angular and I dont know why...I tried different things but all have the same output - not recognizing angular

1. I download angular.min.js from angular website and add link to this js folder from my page
2. tried  `<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>`no change...
3. tried using package manager console :   <`PM> Install-Package angularjs` added successfully...

here is a full code from my HTML page...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="test">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//app.js

```
 (function () {

        var app = angular.module('test',[]);

    });
```

*UPDATE: I get this error :

```
Unhandled exception at line 7, column 218 in http://localhost:4191/Scripts/angular.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected
```

**Solution : I used angular.min.js -   changes it to src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js". problem solved.**

Comment: It's not recognising how? Error on <script line? Error on first line to use angular? Error elsewhere?

Comment: oh sorry, I get this error :Unhandled exception at line 7, column 218 in http://localhost:4191/Scripts/angular.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: show us your app.js file please. it will be great if you will add it into your question.

Comment: KryDos - did it, thanks.

Comment: is not necessary to use (function(){}). please remove it.

Comment: Did it - I removed  (function(){}) and still get error..and now I get this error too - Object doesn't support property or method 'module'

Comment: @Damkulul, which browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63665/discussion-between-krydos-and-damkulul).

Answer (score 4):

According to the comments on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749970/angular-js-script5007-object-expected-error-in-ie9-and-ie10-upon-loading-the)  the page needs the following mark-up

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: This worked for me. Using IE 10 and AngularJS v1.4.3.